# setsize stopped working today

Tags: facebook, iframe, height, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have several iframe apps that stopped vertical resizing today. Has anyone else noticed an issue? Here is the small excerpt from my code that does the resizing on several apps:

```
if (appsettings.minheight != "null") 
{
    FB.XFBML.parse();
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: '810px', height: appsettings.minheight + "px" });        
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

appsettings.minheight does have a value, and this was working fine recently. From the docs:

> ```
> Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" in the Developer App.
> ```

I double checked this, and the app settings were all set to fluid, but this has been the case for a while. I tried toggling to Fixed (and setting a value) earlier today, but still no luck. I do not have a setting called "Settable."

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: A guess: Try without the "px" like in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/): `FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });`

Comment: Yep. That's exactly it. Passing integers in solved the problem. I guess a recent change to the SDK now requires integers. Thanks.

Comment: It was only a guess, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. Let me catch up on it...

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the "px" like in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/): `FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });`